# Jgrowl like notification using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there anything in Dojo like the [jquery jgrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html).

Answer (score 8):

There exists `dojox.widget.Toaster`. ([Test-File](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/dojo-release-1.6.1/dojox/widget/tests/test_Toaster.html) & [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/widget/Toaster))

You need to create a new channel with the Toaster, for example.

```
var errors = new dojox.widget.Toaster({
    messageTopic: '/app/error',
    positionDirection: 'br-up',
    duration: 5000
});
```

After this you can publish with `dojo.publish` to the channel `/app/error`

```
dojo.publish('/app/error', ["Error sending data"]);
```

Don't forget to load the Toaster CSS `dojox/widget/Toaster/Toaster.css`

If you want it black, you need to change the CSS. I created an example with two Toasters, one displays new messages in the right upper corner, the other in the right bottom corner. And i made them black.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnDbn/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [github project](http://stratease.github.io/dGrowl/).

I was looking for the same thing, but with a bit more features than the Toaster widget provided. So I started the dGrowl project.